# Defining a dependency for (a Python) add_rostest call?

Tags: ros, python, catkin, rostest, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a unit test written in Python that depends on a package that generates messages.  If I run `catkin_make run_tests --only-pkg-with-deps my_package`, the test fails because it can't find the message modules.  (If I run `catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps my_package` before running the tests, the tests pass because the messages are generated.)

Without a proper/obvious CMake target (because Python), what's the preferred way to force catkin/cmake to build the messages before running the tests?  I don't want to have to build everything first, as I believe CMake targets should be self-sufficient.

My current approach, though hacky, is to make my rostest stanza look like this:

```
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
    find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
    find_package(my_msgs REQUIRED)

    add_rostest(tests/my_test.test)
    add_dependencies(_run_tests_my_package_rostest_test_my_test.test ${my_msgs_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220540/defining-a-dependency-for-(a-python)-add_rostest-call?/) by [dustingooding](https://answers.ros.org/users/3314/dustingooding/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-11-06**:
Maybe this issue will help? https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you can pass the message target dependencies to the `add_rostest(...)` call using the `DEPENDENCIES` target:

http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/rostest_configuration.html

So your code would look like:

```
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
    find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
    find_package(my_msgs REQUIRED)

    add_rostest(tests/my_test.test DEPENDENCIES ${my_msgs_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
endif()
```

I think that should work, but I haven't tried it myself.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0